# Import does work in console but not script

Tags: python, import, console

I try to run Sympy, a library for Python but I got a problem...

When I import Sympy in the console

```
>>> import os
>>> from os import chdir
>>> chdir("C:/sympy-0.7.2")
>>> import sympy
>>>
```

It works, but if I make a script with this content...ERROR!
Why ?

This error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**", line 4, in <module>
    import sympy
ImportError: No module named sympy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this..

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/sympy-0.7.2")
import sympy
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will learn more on this function sys.path, thank you !

Comment: While this works, it is a rather temporary solution and you would need to add the first two lines to every script that wants to use `sympy`. The "normal" way is to install `sympy`. For example. via `pip` or download and use of `setup.py`.

Comment: i agree that its a temporary solution,
Another temporary solution is to add the folder path to PYTHONPATH environment variable, then you won't have to add this to any script.. and yes you can always install it in a proper way.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the script from `C:/sympy-0.7.2`.

Better yet, install `sympy`. It will go into your `site-packages` directory
and will be available from anywhere. Going into `C:/sympy-0.7.2` and typing `python setup.py install` should work.